# Sequence of diffusions

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Can every càdlàg semi-martingale be written as a sequence of diffusions? That is, is the set of continuous semi-martingales dense in some Skorohod space?

Comment: @JGWang settles the matter when $D$ carries the Skorohod J1 topology.  But have you thought about employing the M1 topology?  It's not hard to see, for example, that the path 
$$
x_n(t) =\cases{0, &$0\le t\le 1/2-1/n$, \cr n(t-1/2+1/n), &$1/2-1/n\le t\le 1/2$,\cr 1.&$1/2\le t\le 1$,\cr}
$$
converges to the path $x(t)=1_{[1/2,1]}(t)$ in the M1 topology.

Comment: In this case, under one of the other Skorohod topologies would the claim be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C=C[0,1]$, the space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$, is a closed subset in Skorohod space $D=D[0,1]$
(cf. P. Billingsley, *Convergence of Probability Measures*, 2nd ed.(1999) $\S\!\!12$, p.124),  hence the set of continuous semi-martingales
**could not be dense** in Skorohod space $D=D[0,1]$.